# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined Dialogflow Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using Dialogflow InLine Editor, and I'm trying to get results from external API, but I'm getting following error on Firebase logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at video (/user_code/index.js:48:9)
>       at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
>       at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:78:9)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:725:7
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:708:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

  function video(agent) {
    agent.add(`Sure, You can access to external API`);
    const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
    return request.get(url)
        .then(jsonBody => {
            var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
            agent.add(body.data[0].first_name)
            return Promise.resolve(agent);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Problem making network call', err);
            agent.add('Unable to get result');
            return Promise.resolve(agent);
        });
    }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('video', video);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**EDIT**:

I added in **index.js**:

```
`const request = require('request-promise-native');`
```

and in **package.json**:

```
"request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
"request": "^2.88"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Prisoner please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
return request.get(url)
```

Request is already defined as a request object and in this case it will try to get a request property.

If you want to fetch something, you would have to use something else like request-promise. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with `const request = require('request-promise-native');`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was

Add in **index.js**:

```
`const rp = require('request-promise-native');`
```

and in **package.json**:

```
"request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
"request": "^2.88"
```

And change **request** to **rp**. As follows:

```
return rp.get(url)
```